# multi dimensional array of objects c++ - How to?

Tags: c++, object

if had some troubles finding how to exactly do it, so i decided to touch and go on the problem, and it seems a have it working now.

The code is:

```
Flight ***Matr = new Flight**[airportCount];
for(int i = 0; i < airportCount; i++){
    Matr[i] = new Flight*[airportCount];
    for(int j = 0; j < airportCount; j++){
        Matr[i][j] = new Flight;
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < airportCount; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j < airportCount; j++){
        Matr[i][j];
    }
    delete[] Matr[i];
}
delete[] Matr;
```

and when i try to delete Matr[0][0] is sais segmentation error;
yay

any errors i've missed?

Comment: The most basic error here is using pointers and new at all. You reached the "three star programming" level; it's not a positive thing. Just wrap a vector in a class that simulates multi-dimensional access.

Comment: Where do you `delete Matr[0][0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change line `Matr[i][j] = new Flight;` to `Matr[i][j] = new Flight[len];`
and change line `Matr[i][j];` to `delete[] Matr[i][j];`

Answer (score 2):

why not using vectors?

```
vector < vector < Flight > > Matr( airportCount,
                                   vector < Flight >( airportCount ) )
```